# Returning multiple JButton Arrays using factory...?

Tags: java, arrays, return, jbutton

I'm new java student and I need some help with a code.

I am writing a method that contains an array of JButtons and I am using a factory method to make them. Now the problem is, I have no clue how to return the buttons (they have different colors so I had to break them apart). In total I have 4 arrays and I need to somehow return them all...

here is my code

```
private JButton[] createButtons() {
    JButton [] numberButton      =   null ;
    JButton [] operatorButtons   =   null ;
    JButton [] controlButtons    =   null ;
    JButton [] equalsButton      =   null ;

    numberButton                 =   new JButton[10] ;
    operatorButtons              =   new JButton[6]  ;
    controlButtons               =   new JButton[2]  ;
    equalsButton                 =   new JButton[1]  ;

    int index                    =   0 ;

    String   [] calcButtons   =   {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "+", "-", "*", "/", "Sqrt", "%",
                                     "C", "BS", "="} ;

    for (index = 0; index < 10; index++)
    numberButton[index]   =   ButtonFactory.createButton(calcButtons[index], Color.LIGHT_GRAY) ; 
    for (index = 10; index < 17; index++)
    operatorButtons[6]    =   ButtonFactory.createButton(calcButtons[index], Color.CYAN) ; 
    for (index = 17; index < 20; index++)
    controlButtons[2]     =   ButtonFactory.createButton(calcButtons[index], Color.MAGENTA) ;
    for (index = 19; index == 20; index++) 
    equalsButton[1]       =   ButtonFactory.createButton(calcButtons[index], Color.GREEN) ; 

    return (JButton[]) new Object[]{numberButton, numberButton, operatorButtons, controlButtons, equalsButton} ;


}
```

I read somewhere here that I can create an object as I did in the bottom and it would work, but it isn't...

Also, I may need some help adding the actionListener and mouseListener to each array.

Thanks!!

**EDIT ENTIRE NEW METHOD WITH ONE ARRAY**

```
private JButton[] createButtons() {
    JButton [] calcButtons        =   null ;
    calcButtons                  =   new JButton[BUTTON_COLUMNS * BUTTON_ROWS] ;
    int index                    =   0 ;

    String   [] numButtons       =   {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "."} ;
    String   [] operButtons      =   {"+", ".", "-", "*", "/", "Sqrt", "%"} ;
    String   [] contButtons      =   {"C", "BS"} ;
    String   [] equalButton      =   {"="} ;


    for (int i = 0; i < numButtons.length ; i++) {
    calcButtons[i].add(ButtonFactory.createButton(numButtons[index], Color.LIGHT_GRAY)) ;
    index++ ; 
    calcButtons[i].addMouseListener(this)  ;
    calcButtons[i].addActionListener(this) ; }

    for (int i = 0; i < operButtons.length ; i++) {
    calcButtons[i].add(ButtonFactory.createButton(operButtons[index], Color.CYAN)) ;
    index++ ; 
    calcButtons[i].addMouseListener(this)  ;
    calcButtons[i].addActionListener(this) ; }

    for (int i = 0; i < contButtons.length; i++) {
    calcButtons[i].add(ButtonFactory.createButton(contButtons[index], Color.MAGENTA)) ; 
    index++ ; 
    calcButtons[i].addMouseListener(this)  ;
    calcButtons[i].addActionListener(this) ; }

    for(int i = 0; i < equalButton.length; i++){
    calcButtons[i].add(ButtonFactory.createButton(equalButton[index], Color.GREEN)) ; 
    index++ ; 
    calcButtons[i].addMouseListener(this)  ;
    calcButtons[i].addActionListener(this) ;}


    return calcButtons ;

}
```

But my buttons are still null and I can't figure out whats wrong. I assume it has something to do with the calcButtons array.

**Basically**

I want to be able to do this

Ok so basically I want to be able to do this

```
calcButtons[0].add(ButtonFactory.createButton("0", Color.LIGHT_GRAY)) ;
        calcButtons[1].add(ButtonFactory.createButton("1", Color.LIGHT_GRAY)) ;
        calcButtons[2].add(ButtonFactory.createButton("2", Color.LIGHT_GRAY)) ;
        calcButtons[3].add(ButtonFactory.createButton("3", Color.LIGHT_GRAY)) ;
        calcButtons[4].add(ButtonFactory.createButton("3", Color.LIGHT_GRAY)) ;
```

with arrays (including the operations and stuff)...

**EDIT**

Did you mean something like this?

```
for (int i = numButtons.length; i < (numButtons.length + operButtons.length) ; i++) {
    calcButtons[i].add(ButtonFactory.createButton(operButtons[index++], Color.CYAN)) ;
    calcButtons[i].addMouseListener(this)  ;
    calcButtons[i].addActionListener(this) ; }
```

Because after I changed my for loops to this I still get null. I even counted them and everything. Does it have something to do with the index++ maybe?

Comment: Show your whole new method. If you're only creating and returning one array, the method shouldn't contain four arrays of JButton but rather just **one** array of JButton, that the method then fills and then returns.

Comment: Ok so as you see I am just using one array this time. I am also using string arrays to reference what each button should be labeled. I'm getting null, I believe it has something to do with the for loops but im not quite sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You're hard-coding your array indices inside of your for loop which means the code is going to fail since you'll be assigning a JButton repeatedly to the **same array item**, leaving the other array items null. You must use a variable index in both the JButton and the String calcButtons arrays.
- Consider instead using for loops that all begin with i, and a separate index, called index, and incrementing the index with each iteration of each for loop.
- Then using i for your button array indices and index for the String array index.
- Don't use magic numbers as they will eventually bite you in the butt. Use the lengths of the arrays to figure out when the for loop is complete.
- Also your final returned array is the right idea in general, but it should not be an `Object[]`, but rather a `JButton[][]`

e.g.,

```
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numberButton.length; i++) {
  // fill numberButton[i] using calcButtons[index]
  index++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < operatorButtons.length; i++) {
  // fill in operatorButtons[i], use calcButtons[index]
  index++;
}

/// ... etc
return new JButton[][]{numberButton, ..... etc...};
```

## __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_

**Edit**
Regarding your latest code, let's mentally walk through a part of your code...

```
  for (int i = 0; i < numButtons.length; i++) {

     // Line (A)
     calcButtons[i].add(ButtonFactory.createButton(numButtons[index], Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
     index++;
     calcButtons[i].addMouseListener(this);
     calcButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < operButtons.length; i++) {

     // Line (B)
     calcButtons[i].add(ButtonFactory.createButton(operButtons[index], Color.CYAN));
     index++;
     calcButtons[i].addMouseListener(this);
     calcButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
  }
```

So what happens at the line under comment (A)?: You create new JButtons and assign them to your array at array positions 0 to numberButton.length, basically filling the beginning portion of your calcButtons array. OK, so far so good.

But what happens under comment (B) and all similar lines?: You create new JButtons and assign them to your array at array positions 0 to operatorButtons.length.

But is this OK? No, it's not because you're re-assigning all the JButtons at the beginning of the array. Is this what you want to do? Nope because it leaves all the array items at the end and middle of the array `null`. You want to advance to the array JButton items that are **below** the ones that were assigned previously. Is there a way around this? Yep, simply use a variable that you're already working with.

I'll let you figure out how to do this -- I know you can.

Comment: Great answer! I appreciate the help on the for loops. The return however cannot be a two dimensional array or I'll have to change the rest of the program... any suggestions?

Comment: @user3124548: Regarding, `"The return however cannot be a two dimensional array or I'll have to change the rest of the program... any suggestions?"` -- yes, 1) either have only one array in the method instead of your 4 arrays or 2) change the rest of the program.

Comment: Lol, yeah that was pretty obvious. I did as you told me and changed it to one array but the buttons are now null.

Comment: @user3124548: then you are likely doing something wrong, but what is hard to say. Consider editing your question and showing any new code and information at the bottom of your existing question.

Comment: @user3124548: see edit to answer. Now you see why it is important to post your latest code rather than tell us it's not working without showing us. Luck!

Comment: I see your logic. Thanks!
Is this what you meant? Something like this 

for (int i = numButtons.length; i < (numButtons.length + operButtons.length) ; i++) {
  calcButtons[i].add(ButtonFactory.createButton(operButtons[index++], Color.CYAN)) ;
  calcButtons[i].addMouseListener(this)  ;
  calcButtons[i].addActionListener(this) ; }

Still get nulls after that

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Walk through your code in your mind -- see what parts of the array get filled.

Comment: I figured it out!!! It was the index pointing to the String arrays, it wasn't iterating, it would just assign the first one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3124548: I knew you could, congrats!

Answer (score 1):

If the button groups are important, I would consider returning two dimensional array, for example...

```
private JButton[][] createButtons() {
```

And simply `return` using something like...

```
return new JButton[][]{numberButton, operatorButtons, controlButtons, equalsButton};
```